# Is there a convex polygon such that it cannot be tiled with some number of congruent connected pieces?

Tags: geometry, polygons, tiling, plane-geometry

So the title says it all.

I assume that polygons have straight line segments as their edges and that they have finite number of edges.

The number $n$ of pieces is, of course, $n>1$, to avoid triviality that every polygon tiles itself.

Answer (score 1):

Any triangle can be divided into 4 congruent parts, so it's not a triangle.

I suggest that this quadrilateral cannot be divided into connected congruent parts. The sides are $\pi, e, K,$ and $\alpha$, with the last two being [Khinchin](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KhinchinsConstant.html) and [Feigenbaum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FeigenbaumConstant.html). One diagonal has length $\sqrt{10}$.

[image: nasty quadrilateral]

Comment: Is your suggestion based on the strong belief that this quadrilateral cannot be divided in some number of connected congruent parts or you could prove that it is so?

Comment: Could prove it's not dissectable into quadrilateral Q.  Start by looking at angles A&J, which do not sum to Pi. Q must fit into angle A. That introduces two new acute angles to fill. If Q has parallel sides, J can't be filled. Otherwise, the bottom edge can't be covered.

Comment: Maybe it cannot be divided into some number of congruent connected polygons with four sides, but maybe it can be divided into some number of congruent connected pieces which have more than four sides and which maybe are not convex.